Using Azurite as an external data source in SQL Server 2022
I'm trying to use Azure Blob Storage as an external data source in SQL Server 2022. However, I want to use Azurite for local development. I have configured Azurite to run on HTTPS using the dotnet dev-cert. I can create the data source but when I try to read from it using OPENROWSET, it always says

File 'test-file.csv' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it
is used by another process.

I created the data source as follows:
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureStorage
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'abs://localhost:10000/devstoreaccount1/test'
);

Then I try to read the file:
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'test-file.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage',
   SINGLE_CLOB
) AS DataFile;

I made the container publicly accessible to rule out issues with SAS tokens. I can access the blob using a browser from https://localhost:10000/devstoreaccount1/test/test-file.csv.
Since I'm using SQL Server 2022, I'm using the new abs:// prefix.
I tried creating the data source to a publicly accessible Azure Storage container and ran the query against that and it works. So the issue is clearly Azurite-related.
SQL Server 2022 is not running in Docker. It's a Developer Edition installed as a regular application in Windows.

Azurite will use https:// instead of http:// when you tell it to do so - you need to supply it with a certificate to use in .pem or .pfx formats. Have you read through Use the Azurite emulator for local Azure Storage development yet?

Is your SQL Server 2022 instance installed directly on the Docker host computer, or is it running in a Docker container? Docker containers are effectively their own little Linux VMs so from a networking perspective 127.0.0.1, ::1 and localhost are telling it to connect to the container itself. If you want a container to access resources published on the Docker host have you tried using host.docker.internal instead?

Hmm looks like I missed the part regarding HTTPS. But do you think it should work with HTTP too?
My SQL Server 2022 instance is not running in Docker but rather installed on Windows as a regular application.

I configured Azurite to use HTTPS with the dotnet dev-cert and updated my question to reflect that.
